# Android Java is there a dryest way to rewrite multiple if block

Tags: java, android

I wrote this checking block which is running fine, but I wonder if there is a dryest way to rewrite it in one line ?

```
        int allQueues = 4;
        if (!mDeviceSensorGyro )
            allQueues = 3;
        if (!mDeviceSensorLinearAccel )
            allQueues = 2;
```

Comment: I believe dry means Dont Repeat Yourself, but I don't see any repetition here. Plus it readeable, this code is fine to me.

Comment: I'd probably reverse the logic: `int allQueues = 2; if (mDeviceSensorLinearAccel) allQueues++; if (mDeviceSensorGyro) allQueues++;` just to avoid too many constants/magic numbers around.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli: unless `!mDeviceSensorLinearAccel` implies `!mDeviceSensorGyro`, you can't do it that way.  The set of possible solutions is limited because @erwin didn't describe the problem and ask best how to implement it, but rather presented an implementation and asked how to improve it.  Nothing in the question links the two booleans, so we have to assume that they are independent, and therefore `allQueues` should be 2 even if `mDeviceSensorGyro` is true.

Comment: @fadden spot on! Indeed I assumed too much from the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments... as Pierre said , there is no repetition .. and it's readable... I was looking for more "condensed code" in less lines ... but as he said it's better to be readable...